# How are data organized when written in the Micro SD cards?

Tags: filesystems, hardware, storage, sd-card, ufs

How are data organized when written in the Micro SD cards as there are no mechanical spinning platters like hard disks?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about the specifics of a type of hardware and not about Unix or Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Unix & Linux topic. However here is the answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-volatile_memory

SD Cards, USB pen drives,... use non volatile memory. That means there is a chip where many bits can be stored and they are not erased when the SD card is removed from the slot (power source).

For SD cards, I would say NAND non-volatile memory is used.